# delete persisted object in one to one relation

Tags: java, openjpa

I'm using openjpa as a mapping layer and I have two models :
user :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "user_id_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_gen", sequenceName = "manage.users_id", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int _id;

    @OneToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_image_id", insertable=true, updatable=true, nullable = true)
    private Image _image;
```

and Image

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IMAGES")
public class Image
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "images_id_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "images_id_gen", sequenceName = "manage.image_id", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int _id;
```

it's unidirectional one to one relation.

the problem is that I want to remove image without removing user and when I remove a user then remove image associated to him.

right now when I delete an image it delete the user as well !!

Comment: just try by removing cascade=CascadeType.ALL

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
I set image field to null and save the user object and then delete the image.